# Finding an invariant polynomial under a matrix action

Tags: invariant-theory, invariance

I asked this question as a mathematica question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41689/finding-a-certain-invariant-polynomial-using-matrix-coordinates

but maybe it will get more attention on this site. 
Let

$a = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a11 & a12 & a13 \\ 
0 & a22 & a23 \\
0 & 0 & a33 \\  
\end{pmatrix},$ 
$c = 
\begin{pmatrix}
c11 & c12 & c13 \\ 
0 & c22 & c23 \\
0 & 0 & c33 \\  
\end{pmatrix},$ 
$r = 
\begin{pmatrix}
r11 & r12 & r13 \\ 
0 & r22 & r23 \\
0 & 0 & r33 \\  
\end{pmatrix},$ 
$s = 
\begin{pmatrix}
s11 & s12 & s13 \\ 
0 & s22 & s23 \\
0 & 0 & s33 \\  
\end{pmatrix},$ 
$u = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & u12 & u13 \\ 
0 & 1 & u23 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\  
\end{pmatrix}$

be $3\times 3$ matrices. 
Consider the conjugation of $a,c,r,s$ by $u$:

$uau^{-1}= \small\begin{pmatrix}
a11 & a12 + (a22 - a11 )u12 &  
  a13 + a23 u12 - a12 u23  + (a33 - a11 )u13 + (a11- a22 )u12 u23\\ 
0 & a22 & a23 + (a33- a22 )u23 \\ 
0 & 0 & a33 \\ 
\end{pmatrix},$

$ucu^{-1}= \small\begin{pmatrix}
c11 & c12 + (c22 - c11 )u12 &  
  c13 + c23 u12 - c12 u23  + (c33 - c11 )u13 + (c11- c22 )u12 u23\\ 
0 & c22 & c23 + (c33- c22 )u23 \\ 
0 & 0 & c33 \\ 
\end{pmatrix},$

$uru^{-1}= \small\begin{pmatrix}
r11 & r12 + (r22 - r11 )u12 &  
  r13 + r23 u12 - r12 u23  + (r33 - r11 )u13 + (r11- r22 )u12 u23\\ 
0 & r22 & r23 + (r33- r22 )u23 \\ 
0 & 0 & r33 \\ 
\end{pmatrix},$

$usu^{-1}= \small\begin{pmatrix}
s11 & s12 + (s22 - s11 )u12 &  
  s13 + s23 u12 - s12 u23  + (s33 - s11 )u13 + (s11- s22 )u12 u23\\ 
0 & s22 & s23 + (s33- s22 )u23 \\ 
0 & 0 & s33 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.$

I would like to find an $U$-invariant polynomial $f$ in the coordinates of $a,c,r,s$ (not necessarily all) such that at least one of the monomials of $f$ is divisible by the $(1,3)$-entry of $a,c,r$, or $s$.

$\textbf{Example:}$ $(a11-a22)c12-(c11-c22)a12$ is an invariant but none of the monomials are divisible by $a13$ or $c13$.

Here's another homogeneous degree $2$ polynomial $(c11 - c33) (a13) - (a11 - a33) (c13) + c12 a23 - a12 c23$ but it is not quite an invariant because under the group action, it becomes 
$a13 c11 + a23 c12 - a11 c13 + a33 c13 - a12 c23 - 
 a13 c33 + (a23 (c22 - c33) + (a33 - a22 )c23 ) u12 
+ (a12 (c22-c11 )+ (a11 - a22 )c12 ) u23.$